# SSH issue from outside home network

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian

My issue is:

I am trying to access a server outside of my network that has a public static IP (PSIP) with ssh, but when I try to use the PSIP the connection times out. I am running the server as a VM of Debian Wheezy.

Example:

```
me@mylocalhost ~# ssh me@x.x.x.x (where x is the PSIP)
connection timed out unable to reach host
```

I go to my vpn set up which puts me on the remotehost network and I am able to access it from there. I have looked through my syslogs and dmesg and found nothing indicating errors with ssh. If I run "dmesg | grep ssh" or "dmesg | grep sshd" I get no output and back to my prompt I go.

```
 ssh -v me@x.x.x.x OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012   
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config   
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *   
debug1: Connecting to 97.90.101.65 [97.90.101.65] port 22.   
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out

traceroute to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets  
 1  mynetwork (y.y.y.y)  1.504 ms  1.460 ms  2.167 ms  
 2  * * *  
 3  * * *  
 4  * * *  
 5  * * *  
 6  * * *  
 7  * * *  
 8  * * *  
 9  * * *  
10  * * *  
11  * * *  
12  * * *  
13  * * *  
14  * * *  
15  * * *  
16  * * *  
17  * * *  
18  * * *  
19  * * *  
20  * * *  
21  * * *  
22  * * *  
23  * * *  
24  * * *  
25  * * *  
26  * * *  
27  * * *  
28  * * *  
29  * * *  
30  * * *
```

Comment: What do `ssh -v me@x.x.x.x` and `traceroute x.x.x.x` tell you?

Comment: Here it is for the first option :  ssh -v me@x.x.x.x
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 97.90.101.65 [97.90.101.65] port 22.
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: There's nothing here... please add the output to the original question.

Comment: And for traceroute:  traceroute to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  mynetwork (y.y.y.y)  1.504 ms  1.460 ms  2.167 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *  the y.y.y.y is my current IP

Comment: This is unreadable, put it in the original question as preformatted text.

Comment: both outputs are in the original question now. Thank you Teun.

Comment: I fixed markup since it was still unreadable (edit pending), but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of possible causes:

1. your router doesn't know how to reach the public IP
2. the public host doesn't know how to reach your host (no return path)
3. the public host has a firewall which drops your connection

What I fail to understand is why you're mentioning VPN if this machine has a public IP.

Comment: My localhost has the vpn for work related issues while out of office. The remote host is hosted on my works servers. We just did a routing upgrade so I am trying to debug why I cannot access this outside of my work network.

Comment: Figures out this is an internal routing issue. I attached to our other network and tried from there. Still not allowing connections through. Either way. This is solved now. Thanks.